# Apache/PHP undefined function curl_init()

Tags: php, apache, function, curl

I have this error message when I compile my program in PHP.
I have these two lines in my php.ini file :

extension=curl

extension=C:\Server\bin\PHP\ext\php_curl.dll

It still doesn't work, can you help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installation, you would need to restart either Apache or Nginx.

Create a stand alone info.php page:

```
<?php 
    phpinfo();
```

Search the page you should see something like this:

```
cURL support: enabled
```

Comment: I indeed have the phpinfo page, but nothing about curl, i do not have this ; http://www.tomjepson.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/phpinfo-.png

Comment: Finally i refreshed the page and it works, thank you !